# $M$ is a coherent left $R$-module implies $M/IM$ is a coherent $R/I$-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, quotient-spaces, coherent-rings

Do you know how to prove that for a ring $R$, and a bilateral ideal $I$ of $R$, if $M$ is a coherent left $R$-module, then $M/IM$ is a coherent $R/I$-module?

I know how to prove the fact if $I$ annihilates $M$:

In that case,  $_RM$ is finitely generated implies $_{R/I}M$ is f.g. too.

Furthermore, for a $_{R/I}N$ submodule f.g. of $_{R/I}M$, we have $_RN$ is f.g., and then is a submodule f.g. of $_RM$ which is coherent. Then, $_RN$ is finitely presented. It follows that $_{R/I} (N\otimes_RR/I)$ is f.p.

But $_{R/I} (N\otimes_RR/I)\cong N/IN\cong N$, and the result follows.

I don’t know how to proceed if the hypothesis of $I$ annihilates $M$ is missing.

Could you, please, give me an advice?

Thanks!

Comment: You should show what you attempted to do or the question will be closed.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I will

Comment: In the question, $M$ must be assumed to be a left $R$-module (otherwise, one would have to consider $M/MI$ instead for a right $R$-module $M$).

Comment: Yes! $M$ is a left $R$-module.